# How to create sub-arrays access the i-th dimension of an array within for()?

Tags: arrays, r

In a for-loop, I run in `i` over an array which I would like to sub-index in dimension `i`. How can this be done? So a minimal example would be

```
(A <- array(1:24, dim = 2:4))
A[2,,] # i=1
A[,1,] # i=2
A[,,3] # i=3
```

where I index 'by foot'. I tried something along the lines of [this](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Indexing-multi-dimensional-table-td4224543.html) but wasn't successful. Of course one could could create "2,," as a string and then eval & parse the code, but that's ugly. Also, inside the for loop (over `i`), I could use `aperm()` to permute the array such that the new first dimension is the former `i`th, so that I can simply access the first component. But that's kind of ugly too and requires to permute the array back. Any ideas how to do it more R-like/elegantly?

The actual problem is for a multi-dimensional `table()` object, but I think the idea will remain the same.

*Update*

I accepted Rick's answer. I just present it with a for loop and simplified it further:

```
subindex <- c(2,1,3) # in the ith dimension, we would like to subindex by subindex[i]
for(i in seq_along(dim(A))) {
    args <- list(1:2, 1:3, 1:4)
    args[i] <- subindex[i]
    print(do.call("[", c(list(A), args)))
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#Build a multidimensional array
A <- array(1:24, dim = 2:4)
# Select a sub-array 
indexNumber = 2
indexSelection = 1

# Build a parameter list indexing all the elements of A
parameters <- list(A, 1:2, 1:3, 1:4)
# Modify the appropriate list element to a single value
parameters[1 + indexNumber] <- indexSelection   
# select the desired subarray
do.call("[", parameters)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Now for something completely different!
#Build a multidimensional array
A <- array(1:24, dim = 2:4)
# Select a sub-array 
indexNumber = 2
indexSelection = 1

reduced <- A[slice.index(A, indexNumber) == indexSelection]
dim(reduced) <- dim(A)[-indexNumber]

# Also works on the left-side
A[slice.index(A, 2)==2] <- -1:-8
```